# What is the best way to handle view that contain more than 4 pickers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I have a view for sign up which contain pickers with custom data for each, number of pickers is not static so it might be from 0 until 6. I used to work in multiple pickers with tag number, but I'm looking for smarter way to do it. I couldn't find any class or way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you initialize a picker, store a reference to it instead of assigning a tag. Standard delegates will provide you a reference to the picker which trig erred an event, compare it to the references you saved and process the event accordingly. Or even better, create separate delegates for each picker instead of having switches at each handler of the single delegate, make sure you are managing the delegates lifecycle correctly.

Comment: How could I create separate delegates for each picker?

Comment: Same as you create any object, by allocating memory and using its constructor.

Comment: Why are you creating multiple Pickers instead of creating single picker ? Create one and display data for each with the help of conditions.

Comment: You could use a UITableView and put a picker in each cell.